# Как пишется «малютка(?)великан»?

Tags: приложение, раздельно-дефис, приложения

*Не знаю, предполагала ли базовая комплектация «ГАЗ-69» амортизаторы, но на Васе их точно не было. Машину на дороге трясло так, словно ее вручили какому-то **малютке(?)великану** вместо погремушки.* (Из современной литературы.)

Нужно писать **через дефис?** Но оба существительных могут иметь оценочное значение (раздельное написание по Розенталю), например:  *Мы с мужем помолились на церковь; на нас глядя, перекрестилась и наша малютка дочь.*

**И еще вопрос**: что здесь является приложением и что определяемым словом?

**P. S.** Пожалуйста, отвечайте в поле ответов. Меня устроит любое конструктивное решение, пусть даже короткое. В комментариях можно уточнить вопрос/ответ или предложить его улучшение. Спасибо за то, что вы соблюдаете правила.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что больше подходит написание через **дефис**.
Погремушку дают именно ребёнку – здесь малютке великаньих размеров (ср.: *завод-гигант*), а не просто маленькому великану (*малютке великану*, или *великану-малютке*, в общем случае игрушки не нужны).

Получается, что ***малютка*** – определяемое слово, а ***великан*** – его характеристика, приложение.  Дитя из рода великанов.

*Машину на дороге трясло так, словно ее вручили какому-то **малютке-великану** вместо погремушки.*
[Цитата из книги «Манюня», [BOOKQUOTES]](https://bookquotes.ru/quote/1109770/)

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, за ваше мнение. Оно мне тоже нравится, но, вот неожиданность, опять не совпадает с моим. Сколько же там решений?! И какое из них ближе к истине?

Comment: @oleedd  *Малютка* – общего рода.

Comment: В речи, без указанного контекста,  малютка (ребенок) могла родиться и от людей и от великанов.

Answer (score 2):

Общее правило [см. на russkiiyazyk.ru](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/defis-prilozhenii.html). Если определяемое слово впереди определения, то пишется без дефиса, а если наоборот, то с дефисом.
В теории возможны два варианта.

1. Без дефиса. *...малютка великан...*, тогда смысл - маленький великан. Определение "малютка". У меня такое словосочетание вызывает образ Гулливера в руке сына великана.
2. С дефисом. Слово малютка употребляется в смысле *I маленький ребёнок или детёныш животного* (словарь Ефремовой). *...малютка-великан...*, тогда смысл - большой ребенок. У меня малютка-великан вызывает образ, максимум, полутораметрового грудничка. С «ГАЗ-69» такой не справится.

Скорее всего, первый вариант подходит больше второго.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за ваше мнение. У вас очень интересное решение, но я думаю немного по-другому.

Comment: "Пожалуйста!" - подметая шляпой пыль у своих ног.  Мне вопрос показался  интереснее многих, и, только решив его, я увидел имя автора.

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ на вопрос**

Я приму один из ответов, хотя мне очень хочется принять оба, чтобы поблагодарить участников за их интерес к вопросу. Со своей стороны я могу предложить **авторский вариант** решения.

Итак, ***малютка-великан*** (как в книге) или ***малютка великан*** (возможный вариант)?

1. В чем здесь **противоречие и трудность выбора**? Сочетание не совсем обычное.  Начнем с того, что в языке это в некотором роде антонимы, то есть слова называют противоположные качества. Кроме того, каждое слово может иметь два значения. Малютка – это «маленький» и «детеныш», великан – это «огромный» и «название вида».
2. Если связь считать **подчинительной**, то надо выделить   приложение/определение и определяемое существительное.

Какое же качество следует считать **главным** – рост/размер (огромный, машину может трясти)  или детский возраст (играет в погремушки)? В том-то и дело, что для нас эти качества **равноправны.** Выделяя то или другое, мы нарушаем смысловое равновесие. При дефисном написании главным качеством будет детский возраст (малютка-великан), а при раздельном – рост/размер (маленький великан).

3. Поэтому лучше выбрать **дефисное письмо**, но при этом **не называть** приложение и определяемое слово, как бы заменив подчинительную связь сочинительной. Тогда у нас получается **«единый образ»**, как в словах *вопросы-ответы, тоска-кручина, друзья-приятели, ум-разум,  обычаи-порядки, правда-истина, купля-продажа*.
4. Похожая ситуация для сочетаний ***злодейка-западня*** и ***проказница-мартышка.*** Там тоже трудно как выбрать форму написания, так и назвать приложение и определяемое слово (по смыслу они кажутся взаимозаменяемыми и равноправными).
5. С точки зрения интонации по слуху можно определить **разные формы письма.**

(1) Так, **с двумя ударениями и паузой** произносится свободное словосочетание (малютка  дочь, малютка  великан).

(2) При дефисном письме и подчинительной связи  (малютка-великан) произношение **слитное, но с двумя ударениями** (основным и вспомогательным). Основное ударение ставится на определяемое слово, а вспомогательное ударение имеет приложение.

(3) В составных наименованиях с сочинительной связью произношение тоже **слитное, но ударения равноценные.**

6. **Вывод**. Если мы хотим, чтобы  слово обозначало равноправные понятия и звучало с равноценным ударением (***малютка-великан***), то не надо считать связь подчинительной и выделять приложение и определяемое слово.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146300/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответам**

Пока я скажу несколько слов не о решениях (хочется увидеть еще и другие ответы), а о самом сочетании «малютка-великан».

Я обратила внимание, что современные писатели в качестве изобразительных средств особенно часто используют **сравнительные обороты**, а также метафоры (скрытые сравнения). Эти сравнения всегда яркие, неожиданные и **напрямую могут не соответствовать** реальности. Они нередко содержат элементы **иронии и юмора**, создавая легкое и праздничное настроение.

Эта, казалось бы, детская книга (Н. Абгарян «Манюня») поучительна и для взрослых, а советский быт 80-х годов изображен с удивительной достоверностью. При этом **без необычных и забавных** сравнений и описаний там трудно обойтись.

**Вот еще отрывки** (продолжение сюжета).

*– Кастрюююлю держи! – орала Маня Каринке, придерживая ногой пакет с картофелем, одной рукой упираясь в железную крышу монстра, а другой ловя откатившийся арбуз. Кастрюля с замаринованным мясом выделывала по полу опасные пируэты...*

*– Васидис! – вел уважительные переговоры с Васей дядя Миша. – Давай, родненький, идем на подъем.*

*– Кха-кха, вннннн, кха-кха, – надрывался Васидис и таки взбирался на очередной бугор тяп-ляп проложенной горной дороги.*